# Authorize function is not working in web security using mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If i use `[Authorize]` i can n't use ajax function and ajax value not pass to the controller.

```
   [Authorize]
   [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            UserType_Bind();
            Country_Bind();
            //Doctor_Bind();
            return View();
        }
```

Ajax Method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CountryID").change(function () {
                var typeID = jQuery('[id$=CompanyTypeID]').val();
                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#UserRefID").empty();
                $.get("Company_Bind", { CountryID: id, CompanyTypeID: typeID }, function (data) {
                    var v = "<option>--- Select Doctor Name ---</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                        v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#UserRefID").html(v);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

if i don't use `[Authorize]`ajax value pass to the controller.

Comment: Is that method there in the controller?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? as long as you use `[Authorize]` it doesn't go through right? if that's the case then the framework thinks you are not logged in

Comment: When i am using [Authorize]  in accountController : Controller via  Ajax control  via Dropdown list list value should not be passed @NevilleNazerane

Comment: yes sir correct @JibinBalachandran

Comment: if you are having issues with `[Authorize]` function, forget the ajax part. try testing empty actions with get requests.